# jasper server pdf without authentication

Tags: jasperserver

I am studying reports in jasper studio.

Now I can know how to upload my report to the jasper server(localhost:8080/jasperserverver),

and also I can view in pdf viewer after logging in.

Now I want users to view my pdf report without authentication, but I can't.

After googling, I got knowing the url

```
http://<your jasper server>:<port>/<report path>?<report-params>&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin
```

And since my credential is jasperadmin / jasperadmin,
i believed it would work, but it is not.

And I have found the localhost:8080/jasperserver uses csrf protection,
if that is true, there is no way to log in using GET parameters....

How do I do that ?

thank you.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work, can you be more specific? Do you get a (error) message in the browser? CSRF protection does not imply you cannot use parameters in the query string.

Comment: Didn't work on accessing with GET to pdf url.  But After googling I found a solution.  Thank you  for  your reply

Comment: Can you answer your own question with the solution and share it with everyone? ; )

Comment: @Kamal Thank you for your response, I have answered my question and added a link

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to interact with Jasper Server by accessing GET, with token parameter.

The token is the key point in communicating with Jasper Server.
It is called token based authentication. To do this work, you firstly configure spring context configuration for token based authentication.

You can find the configuration file in \samples\externalAuth-sample-config\sample-applicationContext-externalAuth-preAuth.xml.

You should discard the part "sample-" of the file name, and move it to 
\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF.

And restart the server, then you can access with below URL.

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver?pp=u%3DSteve%7Cr%3DExt_User%7Co%3Dorganization_1%7Cpa1%3DUSA%7Cpa2%3D1
```

The url has one query string, named principal parameter that is an authentication token. Application server can give users a authentication token, and when user access to a page containing jasper server report pdf iframe, the app server should deliver the token to the server, therefore user can view the report embedded in the application server.

the token paramter format is like below.

pp=u=username|r=groupname[,groupname2][, ...]|o=organization_1[,organization2, ][, ...]|exp=20180117000000|pa1=[arrtribute1]|pa2=[attribute2]

- pp : pp means Principal Parameter, it's fixed string indicating this parameter is a token for authenticating to the jasper server.
- u : means username, and it is NOT the username registered on the jasper server. It could be any. I don't know about this parameter well, so in my case, I assigned it with a user principal registered with my application server.
- r : means group name. Again, I do not know when and why this is used.
- o : organization name. In Jasper Studio, there are commercial version and community(non-commercial) version. In commercial version, there could be more than two of different organizations, but in community edition, there always only one named organization_1. This parameter is for dividing different group who uses this report server.
- exp : exp means expire time. It is for preventing re-using again by web cache, or some other malicious users. The format depends on the configuration file(mentioned above: sample-applicationContext-externalAuth-preAuth.xml).
- pa1, pa2 : means attribute1 and attribute2, respectively.

By adding this token and adjusting spring configuration, you can communicate with jasper server.

For the rest, refer the [link](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-authentication-cookbook/v56/token-based-authentication) please.